# Multiple charts in one figure in Bokeh

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

Is it possible in Bokeh to combine multiple high-level [charts](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/charts.html) in one plot? For example `Line chart` with `Scatter chart`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes (as of 0.8.1), use `hplot`, `vplot` or `gridplot` from `bokeh.charts` See, for example:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/charts/scatter.py#L43

Comment: That's pretty cool, but I'd like to put both `Line` and `Scatter` chart to the same plot, not two plots arranged vertically / horizontally. Is that possible?

Comment: There is an open PR that adds this capability: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/2088 It will be in the 0.9 release in May

Comment: Could you please update your answer as soon as it's ready? I'll accept it as answer then. Thanks!